# Updating SQL Table with MAX DATE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get Max(year) from a date field to Varchar field by returning only the Year
I hope some one could help.

this what I have so far.

```
  UPDATE MasterDraft
            SET 
            Last_title_changed = (select Max((deed_dt) ) 
            From APPRAISAL_Deed_History )
            WHERE MasterDraft.Prop_ID = APPRAISAL_Deed_History.prop_id
```

this my source Table:

```
+---------+------------+
| prop_id |  deed_dt   |
+---------+------------+
|      40 | 1988-07-22 |
|      40 | 1984-03-01 |
|      40 | 2005-07-12 |
|      40 | 1983-07-01 |
|      40 | 1992-01-31 |
|      40 | 1983-01-01 |
|      40 | 1990-01-31 |
+---------+------------+
```

Output on MasterDraft.Last_title_Changed should be  2005

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be `Max(YEAR(deed_dt))`

EDIT: So you want to update all records and use the max year of the prop id? Then move the where clause to your sub select. APPRAISAL_Deed_History.prop_id is not known outside the inner query.

```
  UPDATE MasterDraft
    SET Last_title_changed = 
    (
      select Max( Year(deed_dt) ) 
      from APPRAISAL_Deed_History 
      where APPRAISAL_Deed_History.prop_id = MasterDraft.Prop_ID
    );
```

Comment: thanks but will get The multi-part identifier "APPRAISAL_Deed_History.prop_id" could not be bound error

Comment: Yes, It Work perfect, Many thanks Saver,  but still can't understand it

Comment: @user2722043 In your mentioned query you haven't reference to table  "APPRAISAL_Deed_History" table.

Comment: You want to update all records. So no where clause needed. You want to set last_title_changed to the max year from appraisal_dee_history where the prop_id is the same as in the record that shall be updated. So you need a where clause there. The sub-query gets executed for each record in masterdraft.

Comment: Many thanks Manoj,  I got Thorsten solution work fine without any problem.

Comment: Thorsten Kettner,  Many Thanks for the solution and explanation

Answer (score 0):

```
    UPDATE MasterDraft
    SET Last_title_changed = Max(YEAR(deed_dt)
    From APPRAISAL_Deed_History INNER JOIN MasterDraft
    WHERE MasterDraft.Prop_ID = APPRAISAL_Deed_History.prop_id
```

Comment: thank you, but will get The multi-part identifier "APPRAISAL_Deed_History.prop_id" could not be bound error

Comment: @user2722043 above query will work. Because in your mentioned query you haven't referenced to "APPRAISAL_Deed_History"  table.